# PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON equivalent in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

is there a Postgresql db config that is equivalent to PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON in Sqlite?

Comment: Foreign keys are always "ON" in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

You can test disable all triggers on tables, FK are implemented via triggers on PostgreSQL

Alter table table_name disable trigger all;

Remember enable after ;-)

Regards